# How do I import the Cereal Library into Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, cereal

Sorry for the newbie question. I have it downloaded and have got this far.

[image: ge]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should ask your question more specifically. I will try to answer it.

1. You need to unzip cereal. Then put it somewhere like `C:\dev\cereal-1.3.0`.
2. Right-click your project in the solution explorer, navigate to `Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories`
3. Add this path `C:\dev\cereal-1.3.0\include`.

After that, you should be able to include the cereal headers in your source code.