# serialize with Cereal in MFC

Tags: c++, serialization, visual-c++, mfc, cereal

I'm trying to use [cereal](https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/) (C++ serialization library) in the MFC project.

It works fine if I add an "internal serialize function" inside of the custom struct that I want to serialize.
But, if I separately define ["external serialize function"](http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/serialization_functions.html) outside of the struct, then it gives a compilation error:
*"cereal could not find any output serialization functions for the provided type and archive combination."*

So, it seems the external serialize functions that I defined are not found correctly, and the documentation says:

> External serialization functions should be placed either in the same namespace as the types they serialize or in the cereal namespace so that the compiler can find them properly.

But, my custom struct and the external serialize functions are commonly defined in the project's View class header file:

```
class CmyprojectView : public CView
{
    // other declarations...

    // Custom struct that I want to serialize.
    struct MyStruct { ... }

    // External serialize function
    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, CmyprojectView::MyStruct & s){
        ar(
            CEREAL_NVP(s.x),
            CEREAL_NVP(s.y),
            CEREAL_NVP(s.z)
        );
    }
}
```

Any advice on why my serialize functions are not found?

---

Thanks to @IInspectable's comments, I decided to let the custom struct (to be serialized) stay in the View class header file (`CmyprojectView.h`), and move the "external serialize function"(a term coined by cereal library) to another header file, wrapped in `cereal` namespace (it also works without the namespace, though).

One remaining question is, even if the struct to be serialized is declared as `private`, the external serialize function can access it - how is this possible?

Any additional advice would be appreciated!

<sub>P.S. When using cereal, don't forget to use the RAII concept, i.e. wrap it with `{ }` such as `{cereal::JSONOutputArchive oarchive(ss); oarchive(s);}`, although it's not shown in IInspectable's sample code since the main function's scope is enough and also for brevity I guess.</sub>

Comment: There is no convincing reason why the `serialize` function template must be a class member. Make it a free function instead. If it needs to access `CmyprojectView`'s internal data, make it a `friend`. I don't know the cereal library, but I would guess that `serialize` can be a [hidden friend](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/cplusplus/hidden-friends.html), too.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you for your advice :) I also think creating another header file containing the custom struct and serialize functions would be better, too (not only does it compile well, but also it seems better design). Still, I was curious why the above code does not compile, but maybe I should read about the 'hidden friend' as you advised. Thanks!

Comment: The above does not compile because the `serialize` function template is a class member of the (unrelated) `CmyprojectView` class. This class is unknown to the cereal library, so it cannot find the `serialize` function template (and even if it could, it would have no way of knowing where to get a `CmyprojectView` instance to call the function on). The library will consider either a class member of the class to be serialized or a free function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Intro

The [`cereal`](https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/) library is a flexible serialization framework. One of its features is extensibility, making its algorithms readily available to user-defined types. Extensibility support is generously provided by repurposing C++'s [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) rules.

#### Problem Statement

The code in question fails to play by those rules.

Before diving in too deep, here's a minimal version of the code that reproduces the issue<sup>1</sup>:

```cpp
#include <cereal/archives/json.hpp>

#include <sstream>

struct CmyprojectView {
    struct MyStruct {
        float x;
    };

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, CmyprojectView::MyStruct& s) {
        ar(CEREAL_NVP(s.x));
    }
};

int main() {
    auto s { CmyprojectView::MyStruct() };

    std::stringstream ss;
    cereal::JSONOutputArchive oarchive(ss);
    oarchive(s);
}
```

Dumping the above into a newly created console application project (and [setting up the cereal library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60853147)) produces the following compiler diagnostic:

> error C2338: static_assert failed: 'cereal could not find any output serialization functions for the provided type and archive combination. [...]

The diagnostic is spot-on but doesn't otherwise elucidate where the compiler went looking for a serialization function. Thankfully, the [documentation](https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/serialization_functions.html) covers the rules for "external serialization":

> External serialization functions should be placed either in the same namespace as the types they serialize or in the `cereal` namespace so that the compiler can find them correctly.

This is a bit hand-wavy<sup>2</sup> but gets the main point across: If the `serialize()` function template is not a class member of the class being serialized it needs to be a free function (template) that lives in one of two namespaces. In the sample above, however, the `serialize()` function template is a class member of an unrelated class.

#### Speculation

I suppose part of the confusion here is that C++ uses the same token (`::`) to delineate class and namespace hierarchy boundaries. `CmyprojectView::serialize` could refer to either a free function (template) in the `CmyprojectView` namespace, or a class member of the `CmyprojectView` class. In the sample above it is the latter, and `cereal` won't consider it as an external serialization function for the `MyStruct` class (whose fully qualified name is `::CmyprojectView::MyStruct`).

#### Solution

To resolve the issue, the `serialize()` function template needs to be either a free function template in the same namespace that `MyStruct` lives in, or a class member of the `MyStruct` class.

Establishing the first option is as simple as slapping the `friend` keyword onto the function template definition:

```cpp
template <class Archive>
friend void serialize(Archive& ar, CmyprojectView::MyStruct& s) {
    ar(CEREAL_NVP(s.x));
}
```

This accomplishes two things:

1. It grants `serialize()` access to the `private` parts of the enclosing class (`CmyprojectView`).
2. Crucially, it also turns what used to be a class member into a free function (template)<sup>3</sup>.

With just this change, things will (magically<sup>4</sup>) start to compile. While there is nothing technically wrong with this code I will say that it is difficult to read than it needs to be. A solution that's easier to comprehend is to make `serialize()` a class member of `MyStuct`. This is what `cereal` calls "internal serialization":

```cpp
struct MyStruct {
    float x;

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar) {
        ar(CEREAL_NVP(x));
    }
};
```

This moves the serialization code into the class it is operating on, making it easy to discover. The code will also continue to work regardless of whether `MyStruct` is a nested class, or lives in an arbitrary namespace.

The only wrinkle with this design is that the `serialize()` function template needs to be publicly visible, making it look like it was part of the class' regular interface as opposed to an artifact of the serialization framework.

This can be addressed by making [`cereal::access`](https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/assets/doxygen/classcereal_1_1access.html) a friend:

```cpp
struct MyStruct {
    float x;

private:
    friend cereal::access;

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar) {
        ar(CEREAL_NVP(x));
    }
};
```

That's better but feels a bit clumsy still. `serialize()` is a class member of `MyStruct`, and shows up in documentation or code completion hints for this class. We can fix this by going full circle to the first solution above, and re-apply the hidden friend idiom. Except, this time around the implementation goes into the `MyStruct` class:

```cpp
struct MyStruct {
private:
    float x;

    template <class Archive>
    friend void serialize(Archive& ar, MyStruct& s) {
        ar(CEREAL_NVP(s.x));
    }
};
```

Nothing changed concerning readability: This is still a challenge to comprehend. `serialize()` *looks* a lot like a class member, but isn't.

There are, however, several benefits to this:

- Unlike a non-friend free function, `serialize()` has full access to all internal data, `public`, `protected`, and `private`.
- `serialize()` is not a class member and doesn't show up in documentation or code completion hints.
- The `serialize()` function template "follows" the class around. If `MyStruct` is nested inside a class, the function template will show up in the outer class' namespace. If `MyStruct` is moved to an arbitrary namespace, the function template will show up in that namespace.
- It is tough to call `serialize()` inadvertently.
- The class and its corresponding serialization infrastructure are spelled out in close proximity.

#### Conclusion

All proposed solutions solve the issue at hand. There are trade-offs to be made, and the choice of design is primarily down to personal preference.

---

<sup>1</sup> *MFC types have been stripped. The issue is unrelated to the MFC, and the solution(s) work with or without the MFC getting involved.*

<sup>2</sup> *I don't know the exact semantics of "should", nor why the global namespace is (allegedly) not considered.*

<sup>3</sup> *Into **some** namespace. I'm confident that the rules that govern this are well-defined and were implemented in good faith. Honestly, though, life is too short to follow down that rabbit hole.*

<sup>4</sup> *See [The Power of Hidden Friends in C++](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/cplusplus/hidden-friends.html).*

Comment: What a wonderful answer, thanks a ton! Your speculation is right, I think I didn't clearly differentiate the two concepts(namespace and class). Please let me ask some questions: **1)** You said _"If `MyStruct` is nested inside a class, the function template will show up in the outer class' namespace."_ - what does it mean "outer class's _namespace_"? It's a bit confusing because the two words "class" and "namespace" are used at the same time.

Comment: **2)** You said making `friend` changes the function to be a 'free function'. Could you elaborate more on it? Is it automatically done internally by the language? **3)** How the external serialize function can access the struct to be serialized, even if the struct is declared as private? (As I asked in the modified question). Please let me know if you think it would be better to post these as a separate question. Thank you!